# Paypal Reference Transaction Billing address blank

Tags: paypal

I have been playing with the reference transactions facility on paypal and I have run into a bit of an issue.

Everything works fine right up until I try to retrieve the latest billing address from the customers account.

If I don't do this, everything works as it should and payment is taken.

Based on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/ I have made the call to retrieve the billing address but it comes back with all the fields as null. The name is correct but the address is empty.

Any ideas on this. I can't integrate this into our site if I can't retrieve the billing address.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things related to PayPal and their APIs, they simply hadn't bothered to document the fact that you have to liase with them and contact them for various parts of the system to be enabled.

Initially when using reference transactions I tried to setup a "Billing Agreement" and the API response alerted me to the fact that reference transactions needed to be enabled on sandbox and live accounts in order to function and that they had to do this themselves, not the owner of the sandbox / live account.

Brilliant, undocumented issue no1.

Once that was working, I moved onto testing the use of a "Billing Agreement" to take payment and as part of that you make a request to PayPal for the details of the agreement so as to ensure its still active and to get the customers delivery address.

I do that and everything comes back as expected apart from the delivery address...

After much head scratching I contact their technical support who informs me that again, this needs to be enabled on the sandbox / merchant account before it will return the address.

Seriously, I know that PayPals documentation is quite poor but this just takes the biscuit.  So if anyone has any issues with reference transactions, just contact them and ask them to enable EVERYTHING related to it and explain what they have done.